# Quantiles from histogram?

Tags: distributions, quantiles, discrete-data, qq-plot

Is it possible to calculate quantiles from a probability histogram P(x) rather than from the data x itself? I have an unbinned histogram for discrete random variables, and I'm wondering if I can calculate the quantiles directly from this.

Comment: You can typically get *approximate* quantiles, specifically, you can usually deduce in which bin a quantile lies - but you can't get the specific value of the quantile. Which leads me to a question: what is an "unbinned" histogram?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I have the probabilities associated with every possible value for x, since x is discrete. What do you suggest?

Comment: @user2561523 Then you have the entire distribution!

Answer (score 4):

Just use the definition of the quantile: since you have the probabilities $p_x$ for all possible outcomes $x$ (which I'll assume numerical, since otherwise the concept of a "quantile" makes no sense), for any $p\in(0,1)$, add up the $p_x$ in increasing order of $x$ until you reach a total of $p$. Formally, a quantile $q_p$ for a level $p$ is

$$q_p := \text{min}\bigg\{y\colon \sum_{x\leq y} p_x \geq p\bigg\}.$$

(Actually, this - or something like this, see the remark below - is the *definition* of the quantile, so it comes logically before any data. Any "sample" quantile derived from observations is an *estimate* of these quantiles.)

There are variations in the precise definition of quantiles ([Hyndman & Fan, 1996](https://doi.org/10.2307/2684934)), which you can in principle include in your calculation, but which rarely make a decisive difference.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Are there any additional subtleties in the calculation of quantiles for discrete distributions? I guess I use the empirical CDF to calculate the theoretical value from the inverse CDF of my distribution. Do I need to round (or something else) in the discrete case?

Comment: The subtleties are really summarized in the article by Hyndman & Fan. Essentially, it boils down to what to report if a quantile falls, say, between 1 and 2: report 1, or 2, or 1.5, or some weighted average between the two, etc.

Comment: I see I can calculate the quantiles for the sample based on that paper. How do I calculate the corresponding theoretical values? Just feed in the values for the sample CDF to the theoretical inverse CDF and do a similar procedure as in the paper?